# How to add data in an array? What's wrong with this c++ code? [error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void']

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this question and I don't know where the problem is.

Correct the code below:

```
void AddData(void *data, unsigned int value, int index){
    data[index] = value;
}
int main(){
    unsigned int array[20];
    AddData(array, 10, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

`error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void'`

1. How should I modify the code?
2. Why put "void *data" in the function AddData() rather than "int data[20]"?

Comment: _Why put "void *data" in the function AddData() rather than "int data[20]"?_, that was the question I wanted to ask you. It's a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: I would argue that you don't need `AddData`. Just do `data[index] = value;` instead of calling a function. This function cannot do error checking, it doesn't know the bounds. It cannot do any high level functionality, it doesn't even know the type. It might, I guess, perform logging, but that's a stretch. Just get rid of the function altogether

Comment: @Jeff that would be  array[5] = 10; given the op's code?

Comment: Your second question answers your first one.

Comment: The answer to question 2 is most likely that whoever gave you this exercise expected you to spot that *that* is the problem you should fix.

Comment: The compiler uses the pointer's type in order to calculate the offset from the start of the pointer's value.  So, `real_address = data + sizeof(data) * index;`  The `sizeof(void)` is undefined behavior; what is your guess at its value?

Answer (score 5):

`void*` is a pointer to almost *anything*, and the compiler just doesn't know what it might point to. It's not possible to dereference a `void*` pointer without casting it to its correct pointer type first.

In C++, it's very uncommon with `void*` pointers, because you can use *templates* to get the correct and actual type instead:

```
template<typename T>
void AddData(T *data, unsigned int value, int index){
    data[index] = value;
}
```

Now, when being called, the compiler will *deduce* the type and use it instead of `T`, so in effect the argument-type becomes `unsigned int*` (for the example in the question).

---

With all this said, I recommend you *don't* use plain arrays, and definitely not pointers.

For arrays, use either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
template<typename T>
void AddData(T& data, unsigned int value, size_t index){
    data[index] = value;
}

int main(){
    std::array<unsigned int, 20> array;
    AddData(array, 10, 5);
}
```

<sub>[Note that I pass the `std::array` object *by reference* and not by value in this example. Also note I changed the type of the `index` argument]</sub>

Comment: For the function template I'd suggest using a templated parameter for `value` too, like: `template<typename T, typename V> void AddData(T& data, const V& value, int index) ...`

Answer (score 2):

`data[index]` is the same as `*(data + index)` and for that to work, the size of the elements must be known. In this case, since `data` is pointing at an `unsigned int`, you need to cast it to `unsigned int*`

```cpp
void AddData(void *data, unsigned int value, int index){
    static_cast<unsigned int*>(data)[index] = value;
}

int main(){
    unsigned int array[20];
    AddData(array, 10, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

> How should I modify the code?

I would suggest making it a function template using a `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void AddData(std::vector<T>& data, const T& value, std::size_t index){
    data[index] = value;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<unsigned int> array(20);
    AddData(array, 10, 5);
}
```

> Why put `void *data` in the function `AddData()` rather than `int data[20]`?

Presumably it's inherited from C code and they cast the `void*` to whatever type the array is holding.